# Pikachoose gallery Fancybox: if I want fancy box on only one image

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Pikachoose image gallery. And I want to open a fancybox on one image in which I want to show a youtube video. I have already used this code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var a = function(self){
       self.anchor.fancybox();
    };
    $("#pikame").PikaChoose({buildFinished:a});
});
```

But this code added fancybox to all images in slider. How can I add fancy box to only one image?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which image actually that one means what is the criteria to choose an image which you want to apply fancybox on it.

Comment: <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
    <li><a class="btn various iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RY8nBMGl02M"><img src="/img/gallery1.jpg"/> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/gallery2.jpg"/> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/gallery3.jpg"/> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/gallery4.jpg"/> </a></li>
   </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     var a = $('#pikame li').first().find('a:first').fancybox();
     // or try using the following line
     // var a = $("a.various").fancybox(); 
     $('#pikame').PikaChoose({buildFinished:a});
});
```

Comment: Try using `var a = $("a.various").fancybox();` Kindly delete all the comments from this answer as it is not a good practice to discuss specific points in comments. Thanks